# ¿Qué significa "a poco"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, méxico

¿Qué significa la expresión "a poco" usada en México?

Por ejemplo:

> ¿A poco?
>
> ¿A poco sí?/¿A poco no?
>
> ¿A poco no has hecho la tarea?

Comment: Es como en Argentina decimos: "posta??"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una expresión que comúnmente se utiliza para denotar sorpresa por un evento.

> -"Saqué 10 en el examen de español"  -"¿A poco (sí)?, ¡Si ni siquiera estudiaste!"

Sería el equivalente en México para el "Shut up" estadounidense cuando se utiliza como respuesta a una oración previamente dicha, como en el ejemplo anterior.

No sé cual sería el equivalente en otro idioma cuando se utiliza en una pregunta, como la de tu ejemplo:

> "¿A poco no has hecho la tarea?"

Pero ahí denota sorpresa, porque la tarea es muy larga y él aún no ha comenzado o porque generalmente es muy dedicado y por eso sorprende que aún no la haga.

Comment: ¿A poco? :P ....

Comment: Exacto! @AlfredoOsorio :P

Comment: En el ultimo ejemplo, para expresar la sorpreza, hubiera sustituir el "a poco..." con "no me digas que...".  Asi que una posibilidad para traducir "A poco no has hecho la tarea" seria "Don't tell me you haven't done the homework?"  No es una traduccion perfecta, pero puede funcionar igual asi en traduccion.

Comment: Seriously?, Really?

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers don't make clear enough for my taste the skepticism that I've seen expressed by this idiom.

spanishdict.com has a [helpful entry](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/a%20poco).  In a few of the examples, I will add, in italics and brackets, some English idiomatic equivalents to try to make the tone of this expression even clearer.

> Interjection
>
> 1. (used to express disbelief or surprise) (Mexico)
>
> a. really
>
> El profe dijo que todos reprobaron el examen. - ¿A poco? | The
>   professor said that everybody failed the exam. - Really?

*[You're shitting me! / Get out of town!]*

> b. seriously
>
> No me gusta el café. - ¿A poco? Estás mal, amigo. | I don't like
>   coffee. - Seriously? Something's wrong with you, buddy.
>
> c. for real
>
> Mañana me voy a Alemania. - ¿A poco? | Tomorrow I'm going to Germany.
>   - For real?
>
> PHRASE
>
> 2. (near; used with "de")
>
> a. close
>
> Estamos a poco de ganar el campeonato. | We're close to winning the
>   championship.
>
> 3. (used to confirm something) (Mexico)
>
> a. really
>
> ¿A poco le dijiste a tu jefe que era un ratero? | Did you really call
>   your boss a thief?

*[Are you serious?  You can't have told your boss he's a thief.  No way!]*

> b. seriously
>
> ¿A poco no van a ir de vacaciones en Semana Santa? | Are you seriously
>   not going on vacation during Holy Week?

*[I can't believe [what I heard, that] you all aren't going away for Easter break.]*

> 4. (colloquial) (used to ask for agreement; used with "no") (Mexico)
>
> a. right
>
> Las quesadillas hechas con tortillas de maíz saben mejor,
>   ¿a poco no? | Quesadillas made with corn tortillas taste better,
>   right?

*[Corn tortillas make the best quesadillas, don't you agree?]*

> b. no direct translation

*[Don't you agree?]*

> Esta camisa me queda muy bien, ¿a poco no? | This shirt looks really
>   good on me, doesn't it?
>
> Esos cuates son bien sangrones, ¿a poco no? | Those guys are really
>   annoying, aren't they?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de @aparente001 arriba. _"A poco"_  lleva consigo una nota de duda o desconfianza, la cual, dependiendo del contexto y la relación entre los hablantes, puede ser amigable, o insultante. Si un amigo le dice a otro: _"A poco deveras te sacaste 100 en el examen?"_, el amigo le respondería _"Si, que no me crees?"_, y se vería como una interacción entre amigos; pero si un jefe le dice a un subalterno, _"A poco ya cerró Ud. la venta a ese cliente?"_, el empleado podría sentirse un poco ofendido por la duda implicita en la pregunta, por el _"A poco"_.

Comment: @JorgeO-L - Me gustan los ejemplos que propones.  // Tienes suficiente reputación para apoyar la respuesta con un voto....

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente se puede intercambiar por: "en realidad" o "en verdad".

Comment: o más coloquialmente ¿En serio?

Comment: Yo agregaria que se usa como prgunta, y casi siempre para expresar asombro o duda. ¿a poco [en verdad] fuiste a Europa?!. Ya que de lo contrario, sin ser interrogacion, no aplica. "En verdad si fui", no equivale a "A poco si fui".

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo, podemos resumir que tiene dos usos:

1. ¿En serio?, ¿de/en verdad? Expresa incredulidad (really?)

   > A: Ya tengo hambre
   >   B: -¿A poco? Pero si acabamos de comer...
2. Incredulidad en situaciones como "no me digas que...", "no puedo creer quer..."

   > ¿A poco no traes dinero?

Answer (score 1):

¿¡a poco!?=¡no  me digas!, si no lo dices no me doy cuenta, irónico.

¿a poco?=¿en serio?, ¡no te creo!, ¿de veras / verdad?, ¿no me mientes?, incredulidad

¿a poco sí?=¿en serio sí?

¿a poco no?=¿en serio no?

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=320712&langid=24

¿a poco sí / no...?=¿en serio sí / no...?

Answer (score 0):

En la ciudad de México la expresión "¿¡A poco!?" es interjección porque denota sorpresa y, a la vez, es como preguntándose si lo que escuchas es verdadero, cuando no crees lo que otro afirma. Ejemplo:

> --"Desde hoy todos los policías son honrados"
>
> --¿A poco?